# getAppender return null from xml

Tags: log4j, appender

when I try to read a appender from XML I get return null,

This is my file. xml

```
<appender name="FileInfoStatistics"   class="utils.monitorstatistics.CustonAppenderRollFile"> 
<param name="file" value="Statistics.log"/> 
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
<layout class="utils.monitorstatistics.CustomAppenderStatistics"> 
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
</layout> 
</appender>

<logger name="utils.monitorstatistics" additivity="false">
<level value="INFO"/>

<appender-ref ref="FileInfoStatistics"/>
</logger>
```

and this is the part java where I try to read the appender:

```
Logger mylogger = Logger.getLogger("utils.monitorstatistics");
Appender app = mylogger.getAppender("FileInfoStatistics");
```

getAppender return null